# How to get the encoded byte sequence for a character in the status line?

Tags: unicode, encoding

I want to display the hex byte sequence for the character under the cursor as it is actually stored on disk.

Currently my status line contains `0x%04.5B` which works fine for ASCII/latin1 files but for UTF-8 it only gives me the Unicode code point which is **not** what is actually stored on disk.

For example, for the German letter `Ä` it shows `0x00C4` which corresponds to Unicode character `U+00C4`. But the actual UTF-8 encoding is `c3 84`.

I also know about `ga` and `g8` but I don't know how to use their output in the status line.

What I want to achieve:

- For `utf-8` files show the output of `g8` in the status line
- For `latin1` files show the `Hex ...` part of `ga` in the status line

Comment: You may be interested in the xxd tool or the [Hex plugin I wrote based on it](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-hex)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @D. Ben Knoble’s suggestion, you can capture the result of a normal mode command (`g8` in this example) using `:redir` to store it in a variable:

```
redir => char_bytes
exec 'normal! g8'
redir END
```

Then you can add it to your status line however you see fit (probably with the item `%{}`).

See:

```
:h redir
:h 'statusline'
```

Comment: Watch out for those curly quotes :)